# Why pgbench is very slow when using custom queries?

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking

I've got a simple query `select * from table_name` written down in a file `query.sql`. I launch `pgbench` like so:

```
pgbench -h host -p 5432 -Uusername -t 10 -f query.sql -n db_name
```

And it takes around 2 minutes to execute 1 transaction and 20 minutes to complete the benchmark with 10 transactions. It's very slow considering that if I run `select * from table_name` myself, it executes in less than 2 seconds (returns 50000+ rows).

When I run `pgbench` with its own tests (without giving my custom sql script) it seems to work normal as I get around 200 transactions per second.

I wonder why is it so slow with my script and if there's a way to fix it?

Comment: `select * from table_name` is useless for benchmarking. It only measures raw I/O speed.

Comment: @wildplasser I want to use a complex query, but it runs forever, this is just example

Comment: @jjanes I mean running the query directly, in Datagrip in my case

Comment: Is Datagrip really downloading and displaying 50,000+ rows?  Or is it opening a cursor, and only fetching the first 100 or so?  Is it running on the same host as you are running pgbench from?

Comment: @jjanes it gives first 500 rows and then you click “next” to see next 500. It’s the same host. Might it make such a big difference that Datagrip shows only first 500 rows and pdbench sends all data? If I enable debugging in pgbench then all I see is “client n receiving” getting printed very fast to stdout.

Comment: @jjanes I’ll go ahead and try to limit output to 500 in pgbench test query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgbench is the one giving accurate results, assuming you need to read the entire data set.  DataGrip is reading only a subset of the rows upfront.  If you were to add a LIMIT to pgbench's query, it would also be faster.

2 minutes still seems pretty slow for 50,000 rows from `select * from table_name`, unless the rows are very wide, or the network is very slow, or pgbench is in the midst of a swapping/paging storm due to RAM constraints.

Note that pgbench reads the entire result set (for any given query) into memory, and so might run into memory problems for very large result sets.